# Android: Changing the ListView data dynamically from other Activity

Tags: android, listview

I have an **Activity_A** where there is a **ListView** whose data depends on a value say **dependency**

From this **Activity_B** user goes to **Activity_B** where he can change the value of **dependency**

since this dependency must change the data in the ListView i need to reload the ListView, hence i did this:

```
if(//dependency is changed){
Intent intent = new Intent(Activity_B.this,Activity_A.class);
startActivity(intent);
}
```

the ListView is populated with new data.

**Problem:**

when i press device back button from this newly loaded Activity_A twice, I end up in Activit_A with previous ListView data. So, if i try to click any item i get this **Exception**

```
The content of the adapter has changed but ListView  did not receive a notification. Make sure the content of your adapter is not modified from a background thread, but only from the UI thread
```

How to avoid this??

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store `dependency` value in `SharedPreferences` and populate your list based on the `dependency` value in the `Activity_A`  `onResume()`

Answer (score 1):

To go back to the previous activity you should not call new `intent`. Just call `finish()` on your `ACtivity B`. Then in your `onResume()` of `Activity A`, update the `listview` with the new values.

Here you are calling `Activity A` as a new Activity, and the previous `Activity A` is still in the `backstack`. So when you press back, you will reach the `ACtivity A`, which was your first Activity. But the values populating the `listview` has changed. So when you try to click on anything, exception occurs. Thats the problem.

So when you change the values to the `listview`, call `finish()` in `Activity B`. It will take you back to `Activity A`. In `onResume()` of Activity A, update the `listview.`

Answer (score 0):

In **Activity A** You have a **ListView**

in **Activity A**, **onResume()** method you set adapter for your **ListView**.

when you navigates to **Activity_B** through **Intent**  and change the value of

**dependency**. on buton click don't start again **Activity A** just finish the

**Activity_B**. Then automatically **onResume()** method of **Activity A** will be called and

again **listview** is loaded. Hence changes effect to values of **listview**

note : Don't forget to declare **dependency** as static.